# How to compare 2 location positions

Tags: android, gps, textview, location, latitude-longitude

I have an App with a `TextView` that finds your location and when you move, the value in `TextView` changes.

I want to know what can I do in order to register the first location and then look for the location 5 min after.

For example:

`min 0

LAT 000000

LONG 000000`

( SAVE IT )

`min 5

LAT 1111111

LONG 111111`

**if min0 == min 5**

**...**

To sum up, I want to compare 2 strings (lat & long at the beginning) and lat & long after 5 minutes.

Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: GPS/3G isn't that precise. Even if you haven't moved a single step away, your GPS position will have changed due to how it works. You need to setup a radius, in which you consider yourself stationary.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[This Link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html) should serve your purpose;

Go through `distanceTo or distanceBetween`. You can create a Location object from a latitude and longitude:

```
Location location = new Location("");
location.setLatitude(lat);
location.setLongitude(lon);
```

**Another Solution I came across,**

There is a standard formula ([**Haversine**](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html)) (that is, it works for any couple of longitude/latitude on earth) but the performance is slow as it needs 7 trigonometric and 2 square roots.

If your couple of points are not too far apart, you can use an `approximate` version (**Equirectangular**), which is much faster.

```
// Approximate Equirectangular -- works if (lat1,lon1) ~ (lat2,lon2)
double x = (lon2 - lon1) * Math.cos((lat1 + lat2) / 2);
double y = (lat2 - lat1);
double d = Math.sqrt(x * x + y * y) * R; // where R is the earth's Radius
                                         // R is 6,371 km
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: There is a better variant of the equirectangular projection: It multiplies with R before your line with Math.sqrt. Then you even sometimes can avoid the sqrt() if you call your method distSqr(): The caller decides whether he only needs the sqr of the distance which is faster. e.g compare with 60m = distSqr() < 60*60: This is faster than dist() < 60  (However in real world I did not notice a speed up of avoiding the sqrt when i measured it on a pc)

Comment: @AlexWien So that would be basically d^2 what the user would be comparing? Correct?

Comment: @AlexWien I liked the approach of going through X^2, but the only question I have is, will it work in all the conditions? Say if the precision is important and we cannot afford the rounding error, since it is going to be X^2. I hope you get what I mean.

Comment: No that can have no influence. since you already have that square in x*x + y*y; you simply avoid the sqrt. and there is no chance that a double overflows in 60.0 * 60.0.

Comment: Ohh No, I am not talking about the overflow, check out this link; http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/205351/addition-of-doubles-is-not-equal-to-sum-of-the-double-as-a-whole

Comment: No that can have no influence. since you already have that square in x*x + y*y; you simply avoid the sqrt. and there is no chance that a double overflows in 60.0 * 60.0. Your comparision value is in meters. squaring a small value is no problem. squaring a huge value could be a problem, but the maximum distance between two points on earth is to small. and usually you compare with small meter values, especially the Equirectangualr projetion only works within say 10x10 km.

Comment: The link is another topic, It shows the usual rounding erros at the last digit. which is the size of an atom compared to distances in meters. You shoudl never compare a double or float with "=="

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks for that @AlexWien. Appreciate it.

Comment: Dont forget to add the value of R to your code (see last line of your code)

Comment: @JNL About the Haversine formula needing 7 trig function calls and 2 sqrt: It needs only 5 trig funcs and the sqrts. Twice the code has `sin(x) * sin(x)` which can be replaced by `sin(x) ** 2` or `sin(x) ^ 2` or `sqr(sin(x))` or whatever it takes in your preferred implementation language.

Answer (score -3):

To compare the two strings, use String.equals(other String), http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equals(java.lang.Object) but the locations and string formatting would have to be identical.

If you wanted to put some kind of buffer on it, so the location doesn't have to be exactly the same, you could parse the string and save the Lat and Long into an integer, then compare it with your delta before triggering your textview update.