# Calculating distance between two points represented by lat,long upto 15 feet accuracy

Tags: java, gps, distance

I have converted the formula into Java provided [here](http://tumblr.jonthornton.com/post/1419487206/calculate-latitude-longitude-distances-in-mysql-with). But accuracy is a problem. We are using GPS coordinates.

We are using iPhone provided GPS location that is upto 10 decimal point accuracy.

```
/*
 * Latitude and Longitude are in Degree
 * Unit Of Measure : 1 = Feet,2 = Kilometer,3 = Miles
 */
//TODO 3 Change Unit of Measure and DISTANCE_IN_FEET constants to Enum
public static Double calculateDistance(double latitudeA,double longitudeA,double latitudeB,double longitudeB,short unitOfMeasure){

    Double distance;

    distance = DISTANCE_IN_FEET * 
               Math.acos(       

                               Math.cos(Math.toRadians(latitudeA)) * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(latitudeB)) 
                           *
                               Math.cos(Math.toRadians(longitudeB) - Math.toRadians(longitudeA))
                           +
                               Math.sin(Math.toRadians(latitudeA))
                           *
                               Math.sin(Math.toRadians(latitudeB))

                       );

    return distance;

}
```

FYI : public static final int DISTANCE_IN_FEET = 20924640;

And then I use Math.round(distance); to convert to long.

For actual 25 feet, I am getting 7 feet output.

Comment: Could you give us some more information? i.e libraries you're using, what the problem is, what some of your code currently is?

Comment: can you post the code you wrote?

Comment: @user2341336 Thank you for reply. 

Problem is I am not getting accuracy. The distance that I get using the formula mentioned in above link, is not same as actual distance. For example, actual 25 feet distance we are getting 7 feet distance. 

Application could be I want to open door when I am 10 feet away from my door. I am pushing my location to server every second. and server has location of my door. Both in GPS coordinates.

Comment: @miah It is simple Java version of code provided in my original post. I push my location to server every second and server has location of given point. As soon as I cross 10 feet barrier it should trigger the event which could be open the door or something else.

Comment: @user890263 - If you don't show us the code, we cannot explain *why* you are getting poor accuracy.

Comment: You're ignoring `unitOfMeasure`. Surely you should be utilizing that somehow?

Comment: Back when we did GPS & distance calculation, we used a different equation from that posted. Though 6 decimals of precision were reported by the equipment.. practically positioning was 3 meters accuracy, sometimes up to 10 m inaccuracy depending on the radio environment. Urban environments & taller buildings bounce signals round.

Comment: As to testing your calculations, capture or obtain (Lat, Long) locations of some test points -- ranging from say, 300 meters away to 4000 km away. You should be able to find the GPS locations & distance between each of New York, Miami, and San Francisco for example. Test these, and some close ranges (300m, 10km) as well.

Comment: @EJP unitOfMeasure is used when I want distance in different units but right now I am returning only in feet so that is why it is safely ignored. Do you see the DISTANCE_IN_FEET = 20924640 constant. It is to calculate the distance in feet. For Miles and KMs the constants are different. Thank you.

Comment: See [Haversine formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula): 'remains particularly well-conditioned for numerical computation even at small distances'. See also [here](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18146848/how-to-compare-2-location-positions/18147220#18147220

Answer (score 17):

You need the [haversine formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula).

Here's my java implementation:

```
/**
 * Calculates the distance in km between two lat/long points
 * using the haversine formula
 */
public static double haversine(
        double lat1, double lng1, double lat2, double lng2) {
    int r = 6371; // average radius of the earth in km
    double dLat = Math.toRadians(lat2 - lat1);
    double dLon = Math.toRadians(lng2 - lng1);
    double a = Math.sin(dLat / 2) * Math.sin(dLat / 2) +
       Math.cos(Math.toRadians(lat1)) * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(lat2)) 
      * Math.sin(dLon / 2) * Math.sin(dLon / 2);
    double c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1 - a));
    double d = r * c;
    return d;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_Positioning_System#Precise_monitoring), 10 feet is close to the limit of what you can expect from normal GPS accuracy.  (And that assumes you are getting a good GPS signal.)  [This post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/43617/what-is-the-maximum-theoretical-accuracy-of-gps) on http://gis.stackexchange.com provides more detailed numbers.  It basically says that 3 meter horizontal resolution is the best you are likely to get with an ordinary GPS receiver.

So if you are comparing locations provided by two different (ordinary) receivers with best case ( 3 meter / 10 feet ) resolution on each, you are still not going to be able to tell reliably if one receiver is within 10 feet of the other.

---

(Note your 10 digits of "precision" may well be illusory.  The real issue is how accurate the locations are; i.e. how big the error bars are ... on two different devices.)

---

> So in that case what other alternatives I have?

The linked articles mention [WAAS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wide_Area_Augmentation_System) and Carrier Phase GPS (CPGPS).  Another option is [WPS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wi-Fi_positioning_system).

Comment: So in that case what other alternatives I have?

Comment: @ThomasW - I assume that that was a comment on the Question, not my Answer :-)

Comment: @ThomasW I have edited my question and provided sample input and result which was given in one of my comments though.

How do I identify if the formula is wrong or the input?

I try not to be lazy. Just need pointer in the right direction.

Comment: @ThomasW and OP please conduct this discussion *under the question.* It isn't relevant here.